# boto3 possible errors while copying from 1 bucket to other

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I have a python boto3 code to copy from 1 bucket to other, but how to handle possible exceptions like source object does not exist, source bucket does not exist, destination bucket does not exist etc.

aws_s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dest_bucket, object_name)

tried ClientError but it gives 404 for every missing case whether it is buckets or object.

so need something like below:

```
try:
    aws_s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, dest_bucket, object_name)
except somexception as e:
     if e.response['some_key_1']=="404":
            print("source object does not exist")
     elif e.response['some_other_key_2']=="404":
            print("source bucket does not exist")
     elif e.response['some_other_key_2']=="404":
            print("destination bucket does not exist")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.